# Eye torturing colors in Vim/GVim terminal

Tags: gvim, colorscheme, terminal-buffer

[image: Too dark blue colors in terminal]
I am using GVim but this happens in terminal Vim too. I use the Gruvbox theme. Whenever I start the terminal using `:term`, I see too blue colors when I change the directory within the shell. The directory names in the shell appear as dark blue, although they appear nowhere when editing text. Also, when I use the shell in some terminal emulator, it doesn't appear as such. I see mild colors in it. How can I get milder colors like the colorscheme?

Vim version 8.2, with a .vimrc file

Comment: Which Vim version?  With or without config?

Comment: Try setting `g:terminal_ansi_colors` and see whether it helps.  See [:h g:terminal_ansi_colors](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#g:terminal_ansi_colors) and https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/21359/17449 .

Comment: It is not recognized as a command.

Comment: @LordRishav what do you mean is not recognized as command?

Comment: @Christian It is saying Pattern not found: terminal_ansi_colors

Comment: @LordRishav that is because this is not a command. That is a configuration variable.